# Flask-Login:Where user_loader callback should be defined?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am new to python coding but straightaway started experimenting with flask. I am having trouble with flask-login extension
Here I am making a simple application which is a blog. This blog is going to be used by one person only.

I cannot understand why the user_loader decorator not working which is defined in models.py. I get exception the application NoneType object is not callable.
My app structure is like this

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- static
|   |   |-- templates
|   |   `-- views.py
|   |-- config.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- static
|   |   |-- templates
|   |   `-- views.py
|   `-- models.py
`-- launch.py
```

app.**init**

```
from flask import Flask
from main import main
from admin import admin
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from .config import config
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager


app_myblog=Flask(__name__)
app_myblog.debug=True
app_myblog.config.from_object(config)
app_myblog.register_blueprint(main)
app_myblog.register_blueprint(admin,url_prefix="/admin"
toolbar=DebugToolbarExtension(app_myblog)
manager=Manager(app_myblog)
db=SQLAlchemy(app_myblog)
Bootstrap(app_myblog)
moment=Moment(app_myblog)

login_manager=LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app_myblog)
login_manager.session_protection='strong'
login_manager.login_view='admin.login'
```

In app.models I have defined User class which does not load users from database. In fact it simply loads user from configuration. In same file I have also defined user_loader callback

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id='1'
        self.name=app_myblog.config['USERNAME']
        self.password=app_myblog.config['PASSWORD']

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(id)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    u=User()
    if u.get_id()==userid:
        return u
    else:
        return None
```

admin.**init**

```
from flask import Blueprint

admin=Blueprint('admin',__name__,template_folder='templates',static_folder='static')
from . import views
```

admin.views

```
from flask import render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from . import admin
from flask.ext.login import login_required,login_user
from flask_wtf.form import Form
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField
from ..models import User



class LoginForm(Form):
    username=StringField('Username')
    password=PasswordField('Password')
    submit=SubmitField('Login')


@admin.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('admin_home.html')


@admin.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login_user(User())
        nextx = request.args.get('next')
        return redirect(nextx or url_for('admin.index'))
    return render_template('admin_login.html',form=form)
```

Whenever i run the routes which have login_required i get the error 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 756, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/home/shivam/Workspaces/PythonWorkSpace/MyBlog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I have this same question. Neither of these answer the question and the docs do not say.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I created a minimal example of your code and the the difference was that I removed the `get_id(self)` function (+ some extra libraries that isn't needed), beacuse it's part of the `UserMixin` class that you inherit.

Are you sure your form is getting validated? Can you describe how you test this step by step? I mean, "go to login.html" -> "enter credentials" -> etc

Make sure which call is causing the crash, is it the `redirect` inside your login function?

Comment: This does not solve the problem.The user_loader callback does not even execute.

Comment: Login is working fine.The redirect is also working fine. But when the redirected page opens then the app is crashed. I think it does not find callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the method in the same place you instantiate the login manager.

ala

```
login = LoginManager
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id/email):
    #your logic here
```

Or import your loginmanager instance from your module and define in your views.